# ps3 controller not turning on or syncing

Tags: ps3

I recently took it apart again to clean it. The only problem was the analog stick was sticking. I put it back together and it wouldn't power on and when it is plugged in the LEDs only blink. I tried the reset button - didn't work.

It is a Sony 6 axis controller.

Comment: When plugged in with the PS3 turned on, what happens when you hit the PS button? Does it blink if you press the PS button when not plugged in?

Comment: It doesn't blink at all if not plugged in when its not plugged in it doesn't do anything

Comment: When it is plugged in just blinks. nothing when unplugged

Comment: Sounds like you might have busted something.

Comment: If it was working before you took it apart then that means you didn't connect something the right way or you busted a cable or something medular to the controller.

Comment: The only thing I noticed was one of the cords from the rumble motor came out if the other wire is still in will that mess with the controller

Answer (score 2):

Ooooh this is bad. PS3 controllers are not meant to be opened.

I'll explain why. The interface with the buttons to the controllers mainboard is literally soldered on before its insolated.

If you don't know what this is. Here[image: PS3 Controller Button handler]

now when you take your controller apart, everything seems so great and easy, it almost literally falls off, right, Wrong, what actually happens when that strip comes off is this. The conductor that's on that circled area gets torn off and stays on the board. Take a look at your strip, if it doesn't look like solid stripes with absolutely no differences between the stripes. you're lucky.

When you put the controller back together, I'm going to assume you have decent experience in connecting wires and things, when you put it back together, you may not have put that precious ribbon in its right place(because it tore off there's almost no way for it to stick to the board anymore) so that may be on the wrong nodes. causing your buttons to not work(hence why it wont power on(if you put it together right, try squeezing it really tight before pressing the PS button on your controller and it may power on)

the only way you can fix this
A: your precious ribbon isn't damaged so bad that it can still pass a decent connection to your main board. In that case, simple hair dryer on the plastic can make it slightly adhesive, but its best to find an efficient way to lock it down in place. your controller will work once more. but don't open it again.

B: your precious ribbons conductive cable was ripped off the ribbon when the controller was taken apart, which is bad, BUT, if you carefully use a small screwdriver, you can grind away the insulation on the ribbon and the main board and try to press it down again. Be freaking careful. this may just get your controller a second life.

C: replace the plastic ribbon. you can replace it. its not expensive either, just be super careful in putting it back together, as far as i know, but don't quote me on it, the ribbon you buy comes with, or is already sticky with a non conductive adhesive. still its easy to replace the plastic if you feel that you may damage your controller in an effort to fix it.

Carefully take it apart and see which side of the connector is damaged.(if any damages) Send photos to this thread, and i will tell you which side to scrape away the insulation.

Best of luck

Comment: I forgot to add that your ribbon definitely has some issue because you cant turn it on wirelessly AND it flashes when you plug it in(this is charging state for the ps3 controller) you cant turn it on there either. Check your ribbon.